# VS2010: Change name of a project library

Tags: visual-studio-2010, libraries

How do I change the name of a project library in such a way to affect:

1) Assembly Information name

2) Physical folder name

3) Referenced name

I tried with normal refactoring but it does not affect all the entries. I.e. old library name="Utilities", new library name = "DataLayer". "Datalayer" should substitute "Utilities" everywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would:

1) Rename the Project in the solution.

2) In the Project Properties, rename the "Assebly name" property

3) Remove the project from the solution

4) Close the solution

5) Rename/Move the Project Folder

6) Open the solution

7) Add Existing project to the solution

8) Re-establish the correct references

9) Delete old solution and project files from new/renamed folder

if I have understood the question (assuming multiple projects are in one solution)..

Comment: Ok. So there is no way to change everything in once?

Comment: Unless you're using external tools, I dont think so.